# What are the good practices with primary keys and business ids for items in JOIN clauses of SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE SQL orders?

Tags: sql

We are exposing through web services and features in GIS layers some data coming from tables of our database. Each record, an "item", has a business id that our caller may use to target specific items when he needs to perform something on them, or ask to learn something about them.
For many reasons not enumerated here, the return of technical ids (such as primary keys) is forbidden.

So, when we receive a caller request, we start a SQL request by :

```
SELECT * FROM customer c 
 WHERE c.customer_number = ...
```

But when comes the time this request has to be completed by some `JOIN` clauses, what is the best thing do do ? Join underlying tables by their business id?

```
SELECT * FROM customer c, purchase_order po 
 WHERE c.customer_number = ...
  AND po.customer_number = c.customer_number
```

or ensure accuracy by keeping the links with primary keys?

```
SELECT * FROM customer c, purchase_order po 
 WHERE c.customer_number = ...
   AND po.customer_id = c.id
```

At the beginning of the life of an application, of course business id will unique like the primary key of the main table describing their item is (but not with the same sequence, not with the same values).
But who can say what will have happened three years later ? What was once an **1 – 1** relation might have become an **1 – n** relation and a business identifier that was unique in a table isn't unique anymore here.

In this case, if I step back and try to seek the most the future I can, what is the best choice during the creation of the `JOIN` clauses of my SQL requests ? Use primary keys or business identifiers ? At long term, it seems to me that the effects won't be the same, but I can't decide.

Thanks !

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: I agree. But it was easier to write sample SQL statements that way for this question.

Comment: For me it is obvious to use the primary/foregn key for your joins and if the relationship between the tables should change from one-to-one to one-to-many you will need to do changes to the foreign keys and other logics anyway

Comment: @Joakim Danielson : precisely, wouldn't the use of business id provide more flexibility  ?